# Discord time stamp bug

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm having an issue on discord where the timestamps are not being updated and followed after blocking and unblocking someone. Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong, any information is helpful!

I've tried changing my device timezone but that doesn't help either